# How do I change the icons on the right task pane tabs

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins, customtaskpane

After updating our Office version, we noticed that when multiple addin task panes are open, a new vertical icon group is appearing on the right side of the task pane, as shown in the following image.

[image: new tabs]

My question is: **is there a way to change the icons on this new tab?**

*Additional information:*

- All taskpanes have an image set on the ribbon. The manifest contains the image definition for sizes 16, 32 and 80.
- The manifest contains a definition for a default addin icon like this: `<IconUrl DefaultValue="myIcon.png" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Currently, the side-tab icon for every task pane of an add-in is the icon specified in `<IconUrl>`, so the same icon is used for all of them. We are working on a feature that will enable you to specify distinct side-tab icons for each task pane.